# Hardlink on same drive gives error about different drive

Tags: symbolic-link, hardlink

I'm using mklink /h to create a hardlink from "d:\some folder" to "d:\some other folder" and Windows 7 is telling me "The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive." But it's NOT a different drive - it's the same drive.

In case I'm barking up the wrong tree, here's what I'm trying to do...

I've created a directory symbolic link from my Chrome profile folder (which IS on a different drive) to my OneDrive folder - so my profile will automatically be backed up. But I don't want to be constantly backing up temp/cache files, so I'm trying to use hard links from the profile folder within the OneDrive folder to folders *outside* the OneDrive folder. Symlinks and junctions don't get the job done because the files are still in the original folders. Help/suggestions, please?

Comment: I can't explain the error message, but the basic problem is that you can't create hard links to directories: only junctions and symbolic links are permitted. Furthermore, I would expect OneDrive to back up any linked files and folders, regardless of the link type, but I have not tested this. The best option I can see is to link all the files and folders you want to include and omit those you want to exclude, but this will be tedious. I would prefer to create OneDrive links pointing to the Chrome directory, rather than create links from Chrome and fragment the profile over two directories.